# Remove extra white space around <input type="image">

Tags: html, css

This is the code I have

```css
#noOfItems{
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   float: right;
   padding: 5px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   border-radius: 20px;
}
#viewCart{
   float: right;
   display: block;
   padding: none;
   outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<span id="noOfItems"></span>
<input type="image" id="viewCart" src="images/cart.png">
```

I have tried setting `padding` to `none` and `vertical-align` to `middle` but there is still white space to the left and right of the `<input type="image">`. The image itself does not have any white space.

[image: blue cart is the image and red circle with number in it is "noOfItems"]

Comment: reduce the width

Comment: Could you upload your actual image and improve your example?

Comment: The actual image is already uploaded. The blue cart icon with red number above

Comment: The only white space I see in the snippet is the 10px margin of the span.

Comment: @LuckyGrewal could you upload `cart.png` and then link it in your code snippet (instead of `images/cart.png`). Then, improve your code snippet so that it actually shows the problem. At the moment, the snippet is not depicting your problem.